# Is there a Way to Cut Sprites at High Resolution (x-px, y-px) and then have <IMG width="" > Resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have noticed that if you use an image src of high resolution and then have the  tag resize it for you, little resolution is lost (1680 x 1008)px -> (250 x 150)px but when I wrote a C++ program to resize the images and append them together, then use a JavaScript to cut of the Sprite images with the default (250 x 150)px the difference is extremely noticeable.

[image: IMG tag auto resized]

[image: Maunaully Resized]

I am familiar with the  technique and changing style="background-position: left up; " but that would force me to use the predefined (250x150) where what I am trying to do is cut up the larger size (1680x1008)px and then have  resize it for me as if you used one first image seen above.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are those pictures supposed to be the same? But they are different in orientation and all.

Comment: they are originally the same size, where the first one is called from <img src="blah.jpg" style="width: 250px;"> where the second is the image downsized to width of 250px and then selected with my javascript as it goes through the Sprite if that makes sense?

Comment: But that's not true. The one is rotated relatively to the other. They're different pictures!

Comment: Yes, they are different picture but originating from the same size.